# can I pull not formatted contacts numbers in Android?

Tags: android, contacts, phone-number

is there any way to get the contacts numbers without any format.
usually numbers stored with (-) e.g.: 089-6543-456
i want to pull the number as 0896543456.

And another question related to this:
can i use ContactsContract.PhoneLookup in order to search for numbers that have partial match and not full match?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See if this will meet what you're looking for with regard to the format:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html#stripSeparators%28java.lang.String%29

As for the second part of your question, you may want to consult the content provider api for searching the Contact provider.

Comment: but how can i use that in a query?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're asking if you can unformat the number during a query to compare it to another unformatted number. I will take a look to see if there is something that would do that.

Comment: that's exactly what i want. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately I think I've hit the end of the road on this one.  I don't have an environment handy to try running some of the lookups using the emulator. Sorry I can't be more help